# Need a hand filling observablecollection into listview or any element that can show data

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, viewmodel, observablecollection

as the question says, I'm stuck at filling a data container (listview) with my content, hopefully someone can shed me a light!

This is the classes that I own (My searchbox sends a parcial name that I want to find on the database,  the query on my database fills and retrieves an ObservableCollection filled with as many parcials as he can find, I then want to show it to my listview, hopefully someone can help me! Thanks in advance!)

```
public class LobbyUserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private DbOperations.DbOperations db;
    private ObservableCollection<Person> persons;

    public LobbyUserViewModel()
    {
        persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        db = new DbOperations.DbOperations();
        searchPersonCommand = new RelayCommand(SearchPerson, CanSearchPerson);            
    }

    public ICommand SearchPersonCommand
    {
        get { return searchPersonCommand; }
    }

    public bool CanSearchPerson(object obj)
    {
        if (SearchPersonBox != string.Empty)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void SearchPerson(object obj)
    {
        Persons = db.DadosForSearchPerson(searchPerson);
        if (Persons != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Persons)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.Name + " - " + item.Email);
                // This works, but I need these 2 items added on a listview
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Noone found with that name");
        }
    }

    public string SearchPersonBox
    {
        get { return searchPerson.Name; }
        set
        {
            searchPerson.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchPerson");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return persons; }
        set { persons = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to raise [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your `Persons` setter. Currently the `ObservableCollection` gets replaced every time you call `SearchPerson()`, but since you do not raise `PropertyChanged`, WPF has no way of knowing that it's changed.

Since you are replacing the collection every time, it may be more efficient to simply use a `List<T>` instead. `ObservableCollection<T>` is only required if you are going to be dynamically adding/removing/moving items in an existing collection.

Comment: coudld you tell me how to implement it in the Set? By code I mean, I'm awake for nearly 30h trying to finish a project and this is one of the 3 things left to do :X Thanks for the intel!

Comment: You already know how. You've done it in SearchPersonBox. Just add OnPropertyChanged("Persons");

Comment: Just did but nothing happens when I tap the button with the command name

Answer (score 1):

+1 for GazTheDestroyer. the solution without OnPropertyChanged would be something like:

```
public void SearchPerson(object obj)
{
    if(!CanSearchPerson(obj))
      return;

    Persons.Clear();
    var result = db.DadosForSearchPerson(searchPerson);
    if (result != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in result )
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.Name + " - " + item.Email);
            // This works, but I need these 2 items added on a listview
            Persons.Add(item)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Noone found with that name");
    }
}
```

your Xaml

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
 <ListView.View>
  <GridView>
   <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  />
   <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Email" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" />
   </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm so full of sleep I can't even think straight, good ridance!